# How to distribute a Go app?

Tags: go

I've written an application in Go. It has two external dependencies that would need to be met before compiling. In the Go ecosystem, what is the best way to package this app for a simple installation process that includes installing those remote deps? How would a user install my app?

Comment: What are the external dependencies?  And do you expect the user to compile or are you talking about distributing a binary?

Comment: I want to distribute a binary

Comment: @Carson Just the binary? When you say "external dependencies" do you **only** mean third party packages (i.e. `go get url.to/package/name`) or are there other files that it needs alongside the binary? Be explicit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- If you are expecting a user to compile your application, and that application relies on third party packages or assets, then I'd suggest just cross-compiling for the supported platforms and providing binaries.
- If you have *assets* that you want to provide alongside the application (a config file, for example) then either: a) package the binary with the assets and tar/zip it up; b) base64 encode the assets and compile them into the binary [see here for a good example](https://github.com/jmoiron/gowiki/) or c) create a build/install script that does this for the user.

If you can clarify your exact requirements it'll be easier to answer more directly.

Comment: +1 for the build/install script in particular. If you can include a reasonably intelligent script (or Makefile) in the source distribution, then it would be much easier to package for package managers.

Answer (score 11):

Go binaries do not have runtime dependencies other than any you might impose in your code.  (Its runtime libraries are included in the compiled executable.)

So you would distribute your app the way you would any other statically-linked binary compiled from C, C++ or other code.

On Linux you might create an .rpm or .deb file using the appropriate tooling for that.  On Windows you could create an installer using a tool like [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: Late response, but any suggestions for MacOS (Catalina specifically)?

Comment: @Chris Assuming you can't just copy the binary manually and run it, You might try something like: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34613/packages (can't vouch for it myself, just what showed up in some searches)

Comment: thank you. I've seen "Packages" get mentioned a few times, however I was trying to avoid using 3rd party tools as much as possible at the moment. [Long story short](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381581/how-can-i-run-an-executable-as-sudo-by-double-clicking-in-finder), we developed a Go app and our users need to download a zip file and then do a `chmod +x myapp` > `sudo ./myapp` in order to actually run it at the moment. Was trying to find a way to automate packaging of the app so that it can be double clicked in Finder and have it prompt for permissions or something.

Comment: That being said I will give Packages a try at the moment because at the moment I don't have a ton of options, seeing as it's not working.

Comment: @Chris Have you tried making a dmg with your program in a Whatever.app folder that the user can drag to their Applications folder? If not I would give that a try.

Answer (score 5):

Go produces a single binary. If your external dependencies are compile time dependencies, then your users do not need to worry about them - they're already compiled in.

If they're run time dependencies, then it is a matter of distributing an exe and related resources, which any installer can do for you - whether the exe was written in Go or not is irrelevant.
EDIT: If it absolutely must be a single binary even with run time dependencies, then you need to convert your run time dependencies to compile time ones. One method is the one elithrar has suggested.

The only thing you need to worry about from Go's point of view is that you have compiled your code for your user's platform.