# How can I statically compile Go programs so they can run in an empty container?

Tags: go, static-linking

I have a program `my_prog.go` written in Go.
I want to statically compile it into a standalone binary that can run inside an arbitrary or empty container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
```

My goal is that I just mount a volume containing the compiled program and the program runs successfully:

```sh
docker run --volume=~/programs:/programs /programs/my_prog
```

How can I accomplish this?

I've tried this before, but got errors about missing libraries:

> /programs/my_prog: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

See an example error report: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/315

Comment: Go does this by default. The thing you must check on is what architecture are you compiling it for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284631/how-to-distribute-a-go-app

Comment: I think I had problems with Go binaries not finding libstdc++.so library before...

Comment: Go itself does not require C or C++ for anything. Unless your app requires cgo, you can easily build a static binary (and even if it does require cgo, you may still be able to statically compile it, but that depends on your app).

Comment: Ok. I'll try to re-check

Comment: It's actually a little bit more complicated than that @JotaSantos, since some stdlib packages use C stblib routines and enable cgo (os/user, net) resulting in a non-static Go binary. You can override that with some knobs (see the pkg docs; using CGO_ENABLED=0 is probably the easiest), but the end result is that in practice many Go programs are *not* statically compiled by default, as `net` is such a common package. If you use a C/cgo library such as SQLite things get even trickier.

Comment: So this is actually a pretty valid question and there are quite a few caveats and exceptions involved.

Comment: @MartinTournoij you're completely right. I got it for granted. I just checked some projects I've used `FROM scratch` and I DO have CGO_ENABLED=0 while building the executable. Now for @Ark-kun (since it is closed for answers: I did this `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go install -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags="-w -s" main.go`

Comment: can someone compile [sic] a comprehensive answer so we have this for prosperity

Comment: Since this question was closed I ended up writing it on my website @RickyA: [Statically compiling Go programs](https://www.arp242.net/static-go.html). Looks like the question got re-opened after the silly close+downvote, but don't really see the value of copy/pasting it here now ‍♂️

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks, that is a very interesting read. I usually work around cgo in docker by just using alpine instead of scratch.